# How to check if a product is within category several levels down

Tags: magento-1.9, php, category-products, category-tree

Hi so I have a hierarchy of categories, the parent of which is Ranges

Each range may have subcategories several levels deep.

What I need to do is check to see if the current product belongs to a category which is in ranges.

For example the product may be in several categories as follows:

```
Tables > Coffee Tables

Chairs > Comfy Chairs

Ranges > Range Name > Range
```

If any category is found which is an ancestor (no matter how many levels deep) or ranges, I want the logic to return true.

Here's what I have so far...

```
<?php 
$_product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
    if(count($categoryIds) ){
        foreach ($categoryIds as $cat) {

            $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat);

            if($_category->getParentId() == '683') {
                $_catname = $_category->getName();
                $_catimg = $_category->getImageUrl();
                $_caturl = $_category->getUrl();

                ?>
                <div class="range">
                    <img src="<?php echo $_catimg;?>" alt="Part of the <?php echo $_catname;?> range" />
                    <span>
                        Part of the
                        <span>
                            <?php echo $_catname;?>
                        </span>
                        Range<br />
                        <a class="btn btn-blue btn-large" href="<?php echo $_caturl;?>">
                            View All
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </div>


            <?php }
        }
    }?>
```

I think the problem is that getParentId only refers to the immediate parent, I want this to return true if 683 is an ancestor on any level.

Hope that makes sense,

Comment: You may recurse that algorithm

Comment: In which file you have tried this code?

Comment: you need the 683's category details if condition return true

Answer (score 1):

Better move this check to your block. I'd recommend use smth like this:

```
    $flag = false;
    $productId = 33;
    $categoryNeedle = 84;
    $cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId)->getCategoryIds();
    foreach ($cats as $cat) {
        $newCat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat);
        $arrayPath = explode('/', $newCat->getPath());
        if (in_array($categoryNeedle, $arrayPath)) {
            $flag = true;
        }
    }
```

If you look through database in path field you can find full path to this category.

[image]